# how to compare hashes of hashes perl

Tags: perl

I want to search `%instancesCD` for the contents of `%instancesTH`; specifically, a match between the `$file` and `$position` keys and the associated value. If `%instancesCD` contains a key/value from `%instancesTH`, then `$fp` is incremented. If `%instancesCD` does not contain a key/value from `%instancesTH`, then `$fn` is incremented. Also, I apologize if the way I am referring to the hashes is incorrect; this is my first time using hashes.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print_accuracy(determine_accuracy(determine_instancesTH(), determine_instancesCD()));

sub determine_accuracy {
my (%instancesTH, %instancesCD) = (@_);
    foreach my $file (keys %instancesTH) {
        foreach my $pos (keys %{$instancesTH{$file} } ) {
                if {
                # ... 
                    my $fp++;
                }
                else {
                    my $fn++;
                }
         }
     }
    return $tp, $fn;
}

sub print_accuracy {
    my ($tp, $fn) = (@_);
    print "True Positives: $tp\n";
    print "False Negatives: $fn\n\n";
}

sub determine_instancesA {
    # ... 
    return %instancesA;
}

sub determine_instancesB {
    # ... 
    return %instancesB;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Should CD contain _any_ value of TH for the condition to be true? Even if there are ten keys in each of them, and only one key/value pair is the same?

Comment: You should always `use strict`. It's good that you have `warnings`, but please turn on `strict` as well. Also, your `%instancesCD` will always be empty. You cannot assign to two list types (hashes or arrays) like that. Perl only passes _a list of values_ and doesn't know where in `@_` one list ends and the other starts. Pass references to `determine_accuracy` instead. All your function names are snake case. Why are your variable names camel case? Decide for one. Snake case is what most people do in Perl.

Comment: hello @simbabque. I did have use strict, but it was creating some errors, telling me to make the hashes global. Then, when I replaced "our" for "my", errors persisted, so that was the only way I could get it to stop.

Comment: @simbabque, Thanks very much for your help, I appreciate it. So I am trying to go through every key/value pair in TH and see if it exists in CD. The condition should be true for each key/value pair of TH that is found in CD, and false if the key/value pair of TH is not found in CD.There should be many times where this occurs, anywhere from 1-5000, and the tp and fn values should be incremented each time a match is found (or not). Does that make sense?

Comment: You should definitely get it to work with `strict`. Looks like you don't understand yet how scope works in Perl. But first fix the problem with `my (%instancesTH, %instancesCD) = (@_);` and [edit] the question to update the code. Then we can talk about the counting.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by pass references to determine_accuracy. I tried this but it did not work:

my (determine_accuracy(determine_instancesa, determine_instancesb) ) = (@_);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138837/discussion-between-simbabque-and-jelly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate one of them and check for the existence of each key. Here is a verbose implementation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %foo = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, x => 7 );
my %bar = ( x => 7, y => 8, z => 9 );

foreach my $key ( keys %bar ) {
    CORE::say $key if exists $foo{$key} && $bar{$key} eq $foo{$key};
}
```

This will print `x`. If you remove the `x => 7` from `%foo`, it will print nothing.

---

Here is there result of the extended chat session we had. A full program that compares the keys and values, with unit tests.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my @test_cases = (
    {
        'name' => 'all keys match',
        'th'   => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
            },
        },
        'cd' => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
            },
        },
        'true positives'  => { surfacecharge => 1, }, # here 
        'false negatives' => { surfacecharge => 0, }, # but this one comes out undef
    },
    {
        'name' => 'key matches, value does not',
        'th'   => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
            },
        },
        'cd' => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'positively charged',
            },
        },
        'true positives'  => { surfacecharge => 0, },
        'false negatives' => { surfacecharge => 1, },
    },
    {
        'name' => 'two matching keys',
        'th'   => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
                88 => 'chronically tired',
            },
        },
        'cd' => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
                88 => 'chronically tired',
            },
        },
        'true positives'  => { surfacecharge => 2, },
        'false negatives' => { surfacecharge => 0, },
    },
    {
        'name' => 'two/zero, one/one',
        'th'   => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
                88 => 'chronically tired',
            },
            areasurcharge => {
                1 => 'stuff',
                2 => 'goo',
            },
        },
        'cd' => {
            surfacecharge => {
                87 => 'negatively charged',
                88 => 'chronically tired',
            },
            areasurcharge => {
                1 => 'stuff',
                0 => 'do not want',
            },
        },
        'true positives'  => { surfacecharge => 2, areasurcharge => 1, },
        'false negatives' => { surfacecharge => 0, areasurcharge => 1, },
    },
);

foreach my $test (@test_cases) {
    my ( $true_positives, $false_negatives ) = determine_accuracy( $test->{th}, $test->{cd} );
    is_deeply $true_positives,  $test->{'true positives'},  "$test->{name}: true positives";
    is_deeply $false_negatives, $test->{'false negatives'}, "$test->{name}: false negatives";
}
done_testing;

sub determine_accuracy {
    my ( $instancesTH, $instancesCD ) = @_;

    my $tp;
    my $fn;

    foreach my $file ( keys %{$instancesTH} ) {
        $tp->{$file} = 0;
        $fn->{$file} = 0;
        foreach my $pos ( keys %{ $instancesTH->{$file} } ) {
            if ( exists $instancesCD->{$file}->{$pos}
                && $instancesCD->{$file}->{$pos} eq $instancesTH->{$file}->{$pos} )
            {
                $tp->{$file}++;
            }
            else {
                $fn->{$file}++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $tp, $fn;
}
```